# How to get a "choose directory" dialog box using Perl Tkx on Windows 7?

Tags: perl, windows-7, tkx

I'm trying to invoke Windows 7's "choose directory" dialog box using Perl Tkx. This is what I'm using:

```
my $dirname = Tkx::tk___chooseDirectory();
```

However, this doesn't display any dialog box, but instead causes my program to hang without providing any error messages. Am I using the function incorrectly? How do I get the dialog box to display?

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:

I won't paste in my full script as it's too long, but simply running the following causes perl to hang for me:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tkx;

my $dirname = Tkx::tk___chooseDirectory();
```

Comment: No, you're not using it correctly.  Have you read the documentation? http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Tk-804.033/pod/chooseDirectory.pod

Comment: @RonBergin That documentation is for the `Tk` module but the requestor is using `Tkx`, so it may not apply to them.

Comment: Does a very basic script such as `use Tkx; print Tkx::tk___chooseDirectory();`  work?

Comment: Seems like that should work.  Can we see your entire program / code that you are using, please?  Thx.

Comment: @tale852150 I have updated my original post.

Comment: Hi epsilonjon, If you haven't already done so, see my answer below.  I used your code stub in a simple Perl program and it seemed to work as I described in my answer. HTH

Comment: epsilonjon, did u ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your script worked fine, without errors, using the code you provided, running under Windows 7 Professional 64-bit with ActivePerl 5.20.2 64-bit.  See image below (blacked-out items are potentially sensitive data):

[image]

Could it be possible that the Tkx screen is being displayed behind another screen?  Try running the code your provided from the MS-DOS prompt.
Also, Tk.pm must be installed since Tkx is a wrapper for Tk.  But I am making the assumption here that other Tkx widgets are working correctly and therefore Tk is installed correctly.

HTH